# on "change" for a dropdown does not trigger when selecting first element

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript

I have a `.sign-up-select` dropdown which is generated dynamically and has 4 values, `['', 'pending', 'cancelled', 'confirmed']`.

```
$(document).on "change", '.sign-up-select', (e) ->
  console.log("Trigger")
```

When I select any of the 3 values, `pending`, `cancelled`, or `confirmed`, my function gets triggered. However, if I select the empty value, it does not trigger the function since it is already the selected element.

I have tried swapping out `"change"` for `"selected"` binding, but it doesn't work either.

**Is there a binding that gets triggered on selection of any value, whether or not it is currently selected?**

Thanks

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/sumeetp1991/63o6ep55/
check this fiddle

Comment: Are you saying it doesn't _ever_ trigger for the empty value? If you select `pending` __then__ select `''` do you see the log?

Comment: @Mathletics I updated my question. I meant to ask if there is a way to trigger the function regardless of whether or not you pick a currently selected value.

Comment: Use `click` or `focus` or even `blur`.

Comment: @Mathletics the only problem with setting `click` is that when you click on the select tag, it gets triggered immediately (see http://jsfiddle.net/63o6ep55/1/)

Comment: Blur will trigger after you focus out, which should solve your problem